# Display entities in a given order

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, azure-language-understanding

The following is my sample utterance -
which product is performing better at sales from the city that is poor at overall sales. I want the entities displayed in the published order.

```
"entities": [
    {
      "entity": "city",
      "type": "entitylistgeographyrelated",
      "startIndex": 52,
      "endIndex": 55,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "city"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "sales",
      "type": "entitylistmeasurevalues",
      "startIndex": 37,
      "endIndex": 41,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "Sales $,amount"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "sales",
      "type": "entitylistmeasurevalues",
      "startIndex": 81,
      "endIndex": 85,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "Sales $,amount"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "product",
      "type": "entitylistproductrelated",
      "startIndex": 6,
      "endIndex": 12,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "product"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "best",
      "type": "entitymaximum",
      "startIndex": 65,
      "endIndex": 68,
      "score": 0.9999881
    },
    {
      "entity": "worst",
      "type": "entityminimum",
      "startIndex": 28,
      "endIndex": 32,
      "score": 0.9999083
    },
    {
      "entity": "product is performing worst at sales from",
      "type": "productgeocomposite",
      "startIndex": 6,
      "endIndex": 46,
      "score": 0.6175548
    }
  ],
```

**Not** in the given order, so I'm in difficulty in mapping the maximum sales for the product or for the city, that's all

Comment: yeah sure. The following is my sample utterance. "which product is performing better at sales from the city that is poor at overall sales". when I inspect the response in Luis I can see the following JSON response,

Comment: LUIS isn't going to change how it returns the data. Are you asking how to map/rearrange the JSON once it is received -- in either Node or Python?

Comment: yes, I would like to rearrange it, is there any feature is available for it in luis

Comment: Saranraj K if you can better define what is needed exactly, I can possibly help you achieve it.

Comment: @SaranrajK I also wasn't able to understand what you want. Could you clarify a little more and maybe provide an example of the desired outcome?

Comment: @artie, actually my requirement is simple, consider I'm asking the following query, show me the maximum selling product from the lowest selling city, for this question 'maximum selling product is one set' and 'lowest selling city is another set', but Luis gives the response for the entities in its own order, so I'm feeling difficulty in understanding whether the maximum sales for product or city and vice versa.

Comment: @SaranrajK Based on your explanation I've just provided an answer I think it will be able to help you. Please let me know it will be of help or not.

Answer (score 0):

LUIS won't change the order of the entities in the JSON. And they are supposed to be irrelevant. If you are relying on the order of the elements to figure out which entity your user are referring to I would advise you to rethink your model.

For example, in the following utterance:

> "Book me a flight from London to Paris"

If you have a single entity called "City" and you tag the entities like this, your are doing it wrong:

> "Book me a flight from {**city**} to {**city**}"

This won't allow you to know which is the origin city and which is the destination city. To try to rely on the order of the entities it's a really fragile technique and probably will get you in a sea of problems.

In this case you should have two entities, one for the origin and one for the destination, and tag them accordingly, like this:

> "Book me a flight from {**originCity**} to {**destinationCity**}"

This way LUIS will, based on the training utterances you've provided, be able to distinguish both entities based on the context of the entity within the sentence and provide you with types that you'll be able to work with without relying on the order of the entities.